# Find smallest string x that can produce two given strings if repeated 0 or n times

Tags: arrays, string, algorithm, recursion

I was asked this question in a coding challenge but my solution passed 8/14 test cases and couldn't solve it 100%. I need in understand the logic behind the question. My approach was to find out if concatenating `t` 0 or `n` times can give you `s.` If so, I return the longest repeating substring of t.

> Given string `s` and string `t`, find the length of the smallest string `x` such that if `x` is concatenated any number of times, we get both `s` and `t`. If this is not possible return -1;

#### Example 1:

```
s = bcdbcdbcd
t = bcdbcd
```

If String `t` is concatenated twice, the result `bcdbcdbcdbcd` > `s` so `s` is not divisible by `t`. Return -1

#### Example 2:

```
s = bcdbcdbcdbcd
t = bcdbcd
```

If String `t` is concatenated twice, the result `bcdbcdbcdbcd` = `s`, so `s` is  divisible by `t`. The smallest string `x` that can be concatenated to get both `s` and `t` is `bcd`. Return its length, 3.

#### Example 3:

```
s = lrbb
t = lrbb
```

If String `lrbb` is concatenated once, we get string `s` and string `t`. Return its length, 4.

#### Example 4:

```
s = rbrb
t = rbrb
```

If String `rb` is concatenated twice, we get string `s` and string `t`. Return its length, 2.

Comment: Isn't the task to find the string `x`? So for example 1, `x` would be `bcd`, because if you repeat it twice you get `t` and if you repeat it three times you get `s`.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

As the question says, x need not be identical to t. Try the shortest repeating substring of s and see if that divides t.